# Accessing view elements in controller cakePHP

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I am creating a form in CakePHP.A snippet of the code is given below. I am trying to pass the value of $i to the paginator function of the generals controller. Please advice me how do get and access the value of $i in the paginator function of the generals controller.

```
echo "<div align = 'center'>";
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
{
echo $this->Html->link($i ,array('controller' => 'generals','action' => 'paginator'));
echo " ";
}
echo "</div>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the variable you want to pass as an addtional array key in the link options, like this:

```
echo $this->Html->link($i ,array(
    'controller' => 'generals',
    'action' => 'paginator',
    $i // Add this after your action in order to call /generals/paginator/$i
));
```